# Linux - How to run programs on external media?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, livecd

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD and the full Ubuntu 14.04 install on a bootable USB hard drive. I have g++ installed on the hard drive, but I need to use the hard drive for sneakernet. Is there a way to run g++ off the hard drive when I've booted off the CD?

Edit: if it makes any difference, gcc is included with Ubuntu but g++ isn't, so I installed build-essentials to the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the *exact same* same Ubuntu version installed on both the liveCD and external USB device ... you *might* be able to get away with the following:

1. Mount your USB device somewhere (for the example I'm using `/mnt/your_USB_device` though it will probably be somewhere on `/media`...)
2. Then, from a root terminal:

`for f in dev dev/pts proc sys; do mount -o bind /$f /mnt/your_USB_device/$f; done`

`chroot /mnt/your_USB_device /bin/bash`

You'll have a root prompt that's essentially running Linux from your external drive.  Try running `g++` and see if it works.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trusting that the hard drive is also Linux.

You can mount the hard drive as a directory to your live CD. You must mount it somewhat like this:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

But the actual values will vary with your hardware. Then, you have to declare the path to `mnt/usr/bin` to be part of the executable search path, and then you have to declare the path to `gcc`'s libraries as part of the search path for libraries.

In short: it's not entirely easy. And it might not even work, if there are major incompatibilities between the `gcc` version and your Live CD.